# Obtener imagenes a partir de una carpeta y mostrar una al azar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estimados!
Necesito obtener la lista de imagenes alojadas en una carpeta específica y luego mostrar una al azar en un div, de ser posible con javascript o jquery. La lógica sería que las imágenes fueran nombradas com img01.jpg, img02.jpg... e incluirlas en algún while, pero las imágenes que son guardadas en dicha carpeta suelen tener nombres relacionados al contenido de las mismas, se adicionan unas y se borran otras, por lo que no me funciona nombrarlas de esta forma. Tengo lo siguiente:

**Div donde se mostrará la imagen:**

```
<div class="azar"></div>;
```

**Carpeta con imágenes:**

```
img/
...imagenx.jpg
...img01.jpg
...otraimagen.jpg
...etc.
```

La idea es que una vez cargue, se muestre una al azar. La lógica me dice, que al ser todas .jpg, debo capturar solamente el nombre de las imágenes en algun array, y luego elegir alguna con:

```
let imggroup = ['imagen1', 'imagen2',...]; // no se como generar dicho array...
let selecimg = Math.floor(Math.random()); // aqui tengo dudas...
let image    = imggroup[selecimg]; // aqui almacenaría la imagen seleccionada desde el array
$('.azar').html('<img src="img/'+imagen+'.jpg" alt="">'); // aqui asigno la imagen al div con clase "azar"
```

Todo esto hacerlo en una función, Mi lio es que no se como crear dicho array a partir de la carpeta, si hay alguien que pueda iluminarme.

De antemano les Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Lo mas facil y viable seria enviar esa lista de imagenes desde tu backend, ¿que estas utilizando para tu backend?,

Comment: Solo estoy usando maquetación, HTML y CSS. el sitio no usa base de datos.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es leer un archivo donde están almacenadas el nombre de tus imágenes, cada vez que agregas una imagen nueva, esta se agrega a dicho archivo. Por lo tanto puedes usar JQuery(si lo usas recuerda refrescar el cache) para leer el archivo, tomar el nombre de las imágenes y así desplegarlas.

Comment: Math.random() retorna un numero entre cero y uno. Para que se muestren la mayoría de imágenes deberías multiplicarlo por el tamaño del array que contiene el nombre de las imágenes. Posteriormente tomas la parte entera del numero generado.

Comment: Es por eso que tengo dudas con Math.random(), ya que para que me diera numero entero tendría que multiplicarlo por un entero, y como no se cuantas imágenes van a existir, es complicado hacerlo asi, se me ocurre que podría multiplicar por el .length del array. No entendí muy bien lo de leer un archivo.

Answer (score 1):

te voy a mostrar un ejemplo en javascript vanilla que funciona, lo que necesitas es iterar por la cantidad de imagenes que tenes almacenadas en dicho arreglo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imagenes" id="listaImagenes">
</div>

<script src="test.js"></script>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var listaImagenes = document.getElementById("listaImagenes"); 
// el id de donde quiere mostrar tu listado, te recomendaría poner los links directamente
// no enquilombarte haciendo la concatenación con el ".jpg"

var arreglo = ["imagen1","imagen2","imagen3","imagen4"]
var NuevoArreglo = [];

var auxiliar;
// primer for
for (var item = arreglo.length; item; item--) {
    var numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * item);
    auxiliar = arreglo[item - 1];
    NuevoArreglo[item - 1] = arreglo[numRandom];
    arreglo[numRandom] = auxiliar;
}
// segundo for
for(var item = 0; item < arreglo.length ; item++){
    var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
    parrafo.innerHTML = NuevoArreglo[item];
    listaImagenes.appendChild(parrafo);
}
```

- Lo que ocurre en el script es, vemos el arreglo, un nuevo arreglo esta sin valores, y también vemos una variable auxiliar
- utilizaremos esa variable auxiliar para ir acomodándolos mediante el método de ordenamiento, método burbuja.
- El primer for se ejecuta automaticamente carga la pagina, y lo que hace es reordenas de forma aleatoria los valores del primer arreglo , "de imagenes".
- El segundo crea un elemento parrafo, en tu caso usa "img" y vas a tener que agregarle la propiedad src, podria ser de esta forma -> si creas -> var img = document.createElement("img") , usar -> ***img.src = "hackanm.gif";***  -> antes de insertarlo en la lista con el innerHTML

sino, este otro codigo sirve:

```
for(var item = 0; item < arreglo.length ; item++){
   listaImagenes.innerHTML += `<img src="${NuevoArreglo[item]}"  alt="imagen ${item}"/>`;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, otro proyecto me impide continuar por el momento, cuando pueda lo retomo regreso a dar informe.

Comment: Perfecto, si te ayudo cualquiera de las 2 formas, creando el elemento , o usando innerHTML, podrías dejar puntos ;) saludos! y espero que te funcione adaptándolo a tus variables!